# TeamCity works differently when running build manually and triggered

Tags: c#, selenium, teamcity, autoit

When running my project's build manually, I first running the agent via console by:

> agent start

In this case, the chrome browser is being opened and I actually can see the tests run. 
However, when running the build by Scheduled trigger, the tests running in background again and some of my tests fails. 
They fails since I'm using AutoIt and found that it only works when running the agent via console. 
What should I do to make it work when running a build by Scheduled trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be not with the trigger (how the build is triggered should not affect build's behavior), but with the way you start the TeamCity agent. If the build process you use requires desktop interaction you need to run the agent from a user session via "agent start". You can configure [automatic user logon](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows) and run the agent on user logon (e.g. with [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx))

Comment: How can I start the agent using automatic logon?
BTW, does it matter if we have ActiveDirectory and every user must use his own User and Password in order to log in to the server(Windows Server 2012)?

Comment: You can configure running "agent.bat start" command on user logon using Windows Task Scheduler or other Windows-specific ways. To configure automatic login you will need to store username/password to do the logon (which is generally a bad idea, but that seems to be the only way to run applications in an interactive session without user interaction)